# Connect hive from flask app using jdbc ERROR

Tags: python, flask, jdbc, hive, jaydebeapi

I'm trying to connect hive database from my flask application but a got this error :

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:hive2://myserverspark:10000/default;
```

this is my code :

```
app = Flask(__name__)

CORS(app)
@app.route('/')
def checkBDD(): 
    database='default'
    driver='org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver'
    server='myserverspark'
    port=10000
    # JDBC connection string
    url = ("jdbc:hive2://" + server + ":" + str(port)+ "/" + database +";")
    conn=jaydebeapi.connect("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver", url,['hive',''])
    print('OK')
    return 'on'

    if __name__ == '__main__':
       jar = "hive-jdbc-standalone.jar"
       args = '-Djava.class.path=%s' % jar
       jvm_path = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
       jpype.startJVM(jvm_path, args, '-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false')
       app.run()
```

note : when i use jupyter notebook all work well

Comment: The error suggests that you don't have a JDBC driver on the classpath that accepts `jdbc:hive2:` urls, or it wasn't registered properly, or possibly the URL has a syntax error that causes the driver to reject it.

Comment: but when i run the same code in notebook it's work well

Comment: That suggests that you have the driver on the classpath in your notebook, but not on the computer where it fails.